# Alternate method to get the required probability without case consideration

Tags: probability

Lets suppose we have 16 different objects and we want to place them in four different boxes containing $4$ each . We need to find the probability of specific two objects lets say $a_1,a_2$ to be together in a box .

> What i did was favourable cases would be:
> $\binom{14}{2} * \binom{12}{4} * \binom{8}{4}*\binom{4}{4}$ * 4 , this is the case of those two to be lets say in first box and then other distribution in rest boxes , and similarily other three cases of those two to be in other three boxes . Sample space would be $\binom{16}{4} * \binom{12}{4} * \binom{8}{4}*\binom{4}{4}$  dividing both  gives the required answer , but i would like if there is a quicker/shorter way to get the same answer .
> This post has that method but i am not able to fully comprehend how it does : [There are 15 balls named from A to O.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3909366/1021792)

Comment: I don't understand how one could get quicker than this. It is juts a multiplication problem once you have the formula

Comment: I mean alterante approach which doesnt lead counting like i did , as to why i am asking , see this problem where the solution given was way shorter than what my method or the op method from that post gives . https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3909366/1021792 @Aplateofmomos

Comment: Say the two specific objects are $A$ and $B$. Once you place object $A$ in a box, think of the placements as $A _ _ _ _ .._$. That is $15$ places for $B$ but only $3$ of them will lead to $B$ being in the same box as $A$.

Comment: 15 places for B?? something sounds wrong there @MathLover

Comment: $B$ can either be any of the $3$ objects in the same box as $A$ or it can be any of the $12$ objects in other three boxes.

Comment: @MathLover in my approach i considered the inside the boxes they are indistinguishable only which of them are what is considered ( that is order doesnt matter inside any box )  . Isnt ?

Comment: But your method is giving them places inside a box too , which i dont get properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345413/is-there-an-alternative-intuition-for-solving-the-probability-of-having-one-ace/1345436#1345436) which explains the method for a similar, but more complex problem solved by many methods.

The answer here is thus simply $\dfrac3{15} = \dfrac15$

**PS**

There they had to be placed in *different* groups, here they are to be placed in the same group, but the idea behind the solution is the same.

Comment: Sir i understood , but how we will reasons that probability will come out to be same as the calcualtion usual one ? I mean without calculating values i mean to show there is a bijection in both methods to give sams answer of proabability

Comment: Whenever **probability** is asked for, it is often possible to avoid **counting** arrangements. Here you can define $E1=$ {event that $a_1$ is in **some** box}, and $E2=$ {event that $a_2$ is in the **same** box as $a_1$}. By the general multiplication rule, $P(E1E2) = P(E1)P(E2|E1) = 1*\frac{3}{15}$

Comment: Understood thanks Sir :)